# How to create Azure Function PowerShell to convert .csv to Tab Delimited .txt file?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a Logic App that creates Comma Separated Values blob "abc.csv".
I then want to run a Powershell Function App to convert its data from Comma Separated Values to Tab Delimited and create a new blob "abc.txt".

I can perform this conversion on my local desktop using Powershell but never used Powershell in Azure Function before so I just need help with the Powershell script in Azure Function to connect to blob, convert existing file's data type and create a new file in blob.

Comment: Would benefit yourself more than us if you attempted to solve this issue yourself first; we could then help troubleshoot your code. Fortunately, PowerShell already has a cmdlet that let's you specify a delimiter: `ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "\`t"`, where `"\`t"` is translated as a tab. This also goes for `Export-Csv` which has the same parameter you can use and should really be mostly all of what you need.

Comment: Cheers for the encouragement. I have successfully created a Function with Blob Storage trigger, and can create a new .txt file using output binding in my Function. I am trying below code:

$body = $inputBlob | ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $body

But instead of tab delimited result, I get weird body in my blob: (body in my blob: ["\"Length\"","\"531\""])

Comment: Where does `$inputBlob` come from?

Comment: It's coming from blob storage.
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "InputBlob",
      "path": "testcontainer/abc.csv",
      "connection": "stteststorage_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blobTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "testcontainer/abc.txt",
      "connection": "stteststorage_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: If I try and save another .csv file using inputBlob content, I can. Means, all the connections and code to create file is working; it's just the conversion code isn't converting from .csv to .txt (tab delimited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easy solution within the Logic App iteslf to replace decodeUriComponent('%2c') to decodeUriComponent('%09')).

Initialize a string variable and use below function expression:
`replace(body('Create_CSV_table'),decodeUriComponent('%2c'),decodeUriComponent('%09'))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to functions, i'd recommend first setting up a plan on a consumption plan. Then fiddling with these functions.

Here is the powershell developer guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal

Python Functions and Powershell have a little bit of a niche in some areas due to how concurrency is handled and being Single threaded by default. I'd take note of that section if you are going to have high traffic.

I think the easiest way to push out data would be taking advantage of output bindings. They are Function's easy to set up connection to another resource in a sense, I highly recommend reading up on them here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell

This is the powershell output bindings which essentially take a connection string and functions host will handle the pushing of data and connections for you to the storage account. All that needs to be done from your end is handling some configuration and setting data to the variable associated with the output binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure Blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?msclkid=145ec9cec4f711ec97eca55f9056d404&tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell) to make the Azure function pickup the CSV files as soon as they get placed in the container of the storage account, then perform data conversion from Comma Separated Values to Tab Delimited and create a new blob using [Azure Blob storage output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell).

To be specific here is how the flow goes

**Step - 1**:
Creating .csv files from logic app and saving them to container of storage account

**Step - 2**:
As soon as the file gets saved to container Azure Function triggers because of Blob trigger

**Step - 3**:
Perform data conversion from Comma Separated Values to Tab-Delimited.

**Step - 4**:
Use Azure Blob storage output binding for Azure Functions to save the generated data to another container.

Comment: Cheers Swetha. I can successfully execute Step 1, 2 and 4, but Step 3 is where I'm struggling. I am trying below code:

$body = $inputBlob | ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $body

But instead of tab delimited result, I get weird body in my blob: (body in my blob: ["\"Length\"","\"531\""])